# FloatingActionButton - Incorrect z-index after scrolling

Tags: java, android, scrollview, z-index, floating-action-button

I have some `FloatingActionButtons` in an Android app, anchored below the title bar in a view where the content below the buttons is scrollable.  On initial load, the view displays correctly, like this:

[image]

As the user scrolls the content on the page, what they ***should*** get to is something like this:

[image]

Notably, with the buttons remaining above all other content on the screen.  However what ***actually*** happens is this:

[image]

Where the buttons are incorrectly rendered behind the title bar.  My layout XML file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="au.com.suncoastpc.coastlive.activity.EventDetailsActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/app_bar_height"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"/>

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        app:layout_anchor="@id/app_bar"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|end"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">


        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fab_facebook"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/fab_margin"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/fab_margin"
            app:backgroundTint="#3c5a99"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/icon_facebook"/>
        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fab_music"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/fab_margin"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/fab_margin"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/fab_margin"
            app:backgroundTint="#008800"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/icon_music"/>

        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fab"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
            app:backgroundTint="#880000"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/icon_info"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_event_details"/>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

...where the `content_event_details` layout has a `NestedScrollView` as its root element and contains the map, details text, and other UI elements that can be seen in the pictures above (basically everything except the title bar and floating buttons).

**How do I make the `FloatingActionButtons` stay on top of the title bar at all times?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hy Aroth,

In You Appbar, add **android:elevation="4dp"** >>>

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/app_bar_height"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">
```

and in your LinearLayout containing FAB,
add **android:elevation="6dp"** >>>

```
<LinearLayout
        app:layout_anchor="@id/app_bar"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|end"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:elevation="6dp">
```

Hope it Helps :)

Comment: android:setElevation --> android:elevation

Comment: Works perfectly.  Although as @wrkwrk noted, the correct tag to use in the XML is `android:elevation`, _not_ `android:setElevation`.

Comment: Ohhhh I'm sorry for that